# Dynamics 365 Online - Error updating opportunity from external batch after v9 update

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Few days ago we had to update our Dynamics online environment from v8.2 to v9.

We have a batch that's running everyday that imports ~100 records (of 4 different entities). In those records some are imported as new ones, the others are imported as updates.

Everything was working fine until the update to v9 version, now the update of opportunities fail on save with this error

```
ErrorCode: 0x80048218
Message: You must provide a name or select a role for both sides of this connection.; [Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins: Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOpportunityUpdate]
[a13c2831-776b-e611-80ec-00155dc14c00: Update of opportunity]
```

Strangest part is that the error happens only updating opportunities (creating new ones or doing any other operations doesn't seems to be affected) and just from code, if i try to update those record directly from CRM, using the same user, I don't have any problem.

**UPDATE 1**

I found out that the problem comes out just when i edit `parentcontactid` with both `null` value, again from UI I can create/edit an opportunity leaving that field blank.

Comment: This error is directly related to connections & connection role. We want to see the code you are using to update oppty and also any other plugin on update of oppty?

Answer (score 1):

Based on error description you provided - this Microsoft's bug. Here is what I recommend to do:
1. Disable (or change step to Async execution) following standard plugin - Microsoft.Dynamics.Sales.Plugins.PreOpportunityUpdate
2. Open a ticket with Microsoft because this is their OOB plugin so they will have to fix the code.

Comment: Fun fact, i can't find that plugin/workflow anywhere in env

Comment: Then ticket to MS is the way to go.

Comment: yep, i was going to open it tomorrow. Btw there's a small edit on question.